# Renaming a namespace in .net

Tags: .net, namespaces

My project I worked on had a codename and this was used for the namespace everywhere in the project.

How can I change it without risking breakage and quickly as well?

Comment: Quite complex if the project is ASP.NET or uses XAML. Resharper and a good prayer, normally :-) Visual Studio if the project is small and simple and a very very good prayer.

Comment: I think if you change it in one file you get that blue fixup box that allows you to globally rename it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do stuff like this pretty safe and fast. Though it is a commercial tool I can highly recommend it.

Otherwise just do a search & replace in the whole solution. This is also fast and should work for most usages of the namespace.

Comment: Search for Whole Word only with match case :-)

Comment: +1 for R#. It is not a free product but it's worth its weight in gold. And it does come with an evaluation period. If you use it to eval and fix your namespace issue you could easily argue that it paid for itself before you ever purchased it.

Comment: The only thing to note is that with R# you'll need a farly good pc :-) :-) It can be quite slow on older machines.

Comment: Definitely true, but even a plain VS2010 runs way better on a good machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to use a regex find and replace in Visual Studio.  This would allow you to control much more closely what you want to find and replace (especially with tagging), for example:

Find

```
Dim {.+} As {.+}\.CodeName\.{.+}\(
```

Replace with:

```
Dim \1 As \2.NewNameSpace.\3.Jobber(
```

Would replace the following:

```
Dim x As New JibberJabber.CodeName.ThingFoo(someVariableOrOther)
```

with:

```
Dim x As New JibberJabber.NewNameSpace.ThingFoo.Jobber(someVariableOrOther)
```

You can always take a backup first (or roll back if something goes wrong).  Just make sure you use the option "keep modified files open" so you can check the changes easily!